# How to Edit "This Workbook" macro with another macro

Tags: vba, excel, module

Just another question hopefully someone can help me with.

For those who have helped me in the past I greatly appreciate this community and I am glad to be apart of it.

Here's some background info.

I have created ~3200 excel Workbooks off a master list (theFILE 1.1.xlsm) each workbook was compiled from a line on the master list.

Now I've been able to edit sheets and cells using this code;

```
Sub Macro2()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim sFile As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim FileName1 As String
Dim FileName2 As String
Dim wksSource As Worksheet
Const scWkbSourceName As String = "theFILE 1.1.xlsm"

Set wkbSource = Workbooks(scWkbSourceName)
Set wksSource = wkbSource.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Replace Sheet1 with the sheet name

Const wsOriginalBook As String = "theFILE 1.1.xlsm"
Const sPath As String = "E:\theFILES\" 

SourceRow = 5

Do While Cells(SourceRow, "D").Value <> ""

FileName1 = wksSource.Range("A" & SourceRow).Value
FileName2 = wksSource.Range("K" & SourceRow).Value

sFile = sPath & FileName1 & "\" & FileName2 & ".xlsm"

'Open Source Row's File
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(sFile)

'(INSERT CODE FOR SPECIFIED JOB)

'CLOSE WORKBOOK W/O BEFORE SAVE
Application.EnableEvents = False
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close
Application.EnableEvents = True

SourceRow = SourceRow + 1 ' Move down 1 row for source sheet

Loop

End Sub
```

Please bear with my lack of terminology.

I would like to be able to use this code if possible to open each Workbook and edit lines within the 'Microsoft Excel Objects' - 'ThisWorkbook'. This module, if you can call it that, houses a BeforeSave Function which logs some info on a hidden spreadsheet every time a user saves.

Here is the Current 'BeforeSave' Macro

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("EDITS")
Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Table1")
Dim newrow As ListRow
Set newrow = tbl.ListRows.Add

    SavePrompt.Show

With newrow
    .Range(1) = Now
    .Range(2) = SavePrompt.TextBox1.Text
End With

Unload SavePrompt

End Sub
```

I need to add .Range(3)=Computer Name and .Range(4)=username to this.
I need each Workbook to work stand-alone as host computers may change sporadically and others won't be able to re-link or edit the VBAs.

First is it possible to edit 'Microsoft Excel Objects - ThisWorkbook'

If so how? I've tried 
    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook").CodeModule.insertLines 13, "Test"

...After allowing Excel to "Trust access to the VBA project object model", I received a notification stating, "Can't enter break mode at this time", I selected "Continue" and My computer didn't like the code while it did open and close each Workbook like normal. It ended up adding "Test" to the Master's "ThisWorkbook". The master Workbook (theFILE 1.1.xlsm) doesn't have a Macro in there so it just added to the next available line from the looks of it.

I then changed the last Code to;

```
ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook").CodeModule.insertLines 13, "Test"
```

This seemed to solve the errors but as the computer runs the code it starts getting hung up and Excel starts begins to appear to "Not Respond.."

So if this is possible...
Is it possible to add/insert a line and move the preceding lines down 1 as it is done in excel when right clicking on a row?

If Excel doesn't allow editing of lines in 'ThisWorkbook' then how do I completely overhaul the Object? (delete and import updated object)

Comment: Please, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48812402/9199828). It's not exactl what you want, but it explains how to edit VBA code with VBA itself. Just adapt it to your needs.

Comment: "not responding" is just your code being busy. You could *probably* get Excel responding again by adding `DoEvents` just before closing the `Loop`, but then that will probably make it slower to complete. Now, how do you *know* the line you want to insert at is line 13? Better locate the procedure you want to replace, find its starting+ending line, and replace these lines (whatever they are) with your new code. First step is to put a breakpoint at `Loop`, and verify that your code is doing what it needs to do, before wrecking 3000 files in one go ;-)

Comment: `ThisWorkbook` (the identifier) will always refer to *the workbook that's currently running the code you're looking at*. `"ThisWorkbook"` (the component name) refers to the "ThisWorkbook" VBComponent of the parent VBProject. That's why you couldn't enter break mode (the code in *this workbook* was modified, and hadn't had a chance to recompile yet), and why getting the VBProject reference off `ActiveWorkbook` worked. That said `wb.VBProject` would be **much** safer.

Comment: Thanks for your Feedback @MathieuGuindon , and after i restarted my machine it ran fine. but it appears that the lines that were already occupied the space and the VBA put the value on the next available line. Is this normal. If so, how do i delete two specific lines so I can have everything in procedural order?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns do you know how to only delete two specific lines? see my previous comment for problem. thanks

Comment: Reference the *Visual Basic Extensibility* type library, and declare typed local variables instead of chaining member calls 5 layers deep - you'll get intellisense to guide you. e.g. declare `currentProject As VBProject`, then `wbComponent As VBComponent`, and `wbModule As CodeModule`; assign each one, then see what members `wbModule` has - you'll find methods to locate specific procedures, what line they start at, and how many lines they are.

Comment: You can delete those 2 specific lines looking for them. Do a Loop that goes trough every line of code in your object and when it finds the one you ant to delete. store the start point and the end point and delete those chars. In the linked answer you can see how to do that exactly, because the answer is *deleting code with code * so it does exactly what you want now.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub Macro2() '''EDIT THE MACRO ON "ThisWorkbook" MODULE
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim sFile As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim FileName1 As String
Dim FileName2 As String
Dim wksSource As Worksheet
Const scWkbSourceName As String = "theFILE 1.1.xlsm"

Set wkbSource = Workbooks(scWkbSourceName)
Set wksSource = wkbSource.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Replace Sheet1 with the sheet name

Const wsOriginalBook As String = "theFILE 1.1.xlsm"
Const sPath As String = "E:\theFILES\" 'this is PATH(!REMEMBER! to include "\")

SourceRow = 5

Do While Cells(SourceRow, "D").Value <> ""

FileName1 = wksSource.Range("A" & SourceRow).Value
FileName2 = wksSource.Range("K" & SourceRow).Value

sFile = sPath & FileName1 & "\" & FileName2 & ".xlsm"

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(sFile)

'''EDIT THE MACRO ON "ThisWorkbook" MODULE - FOR EACH PLANT's Workbook
'Deleting Lines
ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook").CodeModule.deleteLines 27
ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook").CodeModule.deleteLines 25
ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook").CodeModule.deleteLines 21
ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook").CodeModule.deleteLines 19
ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook").CodeModule.deleteLines 18
ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook").CodeModule.deleteLines 17
ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook").CodeModule.deleteLines 16
ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook").CodeModule.deleteLines 12
ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook").CodeModule.deleteLines 10

'Add DIM Lines
ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook").CodeModule.insertLines 10, "'DIM SOME MORE OBJECTS"
ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook").CodeModule.insertLines 11, "Dim computername As String"
ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook").CodeModule.insertLines 12, "Dim username As String"
ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook").CodeModule.insertLines 13, "computername = Environ(""computername"")"
ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook").CodeModule.insertLines 14, "username = Environ(""username"")"

'Add the Lines Back
ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook").CodeModule.insertLines 16, "    SavePrompt.Show"

ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook").CodeModule.insertLines 17, "'If SavePrompt.TextBox1 > 0 Then"

ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook").CodeModule.insertLines 18, "With newrow"
ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook").CodeModule.insertLines 19, "    .Range(1) = Now"
ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook").CodeModule.insertLines 20, "    .Range(2) = SavePrompt.TextBox1.Text"

'Add New Range LINES
ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook").CodeModule.insertLines 21, "    .Range(3) = computername"
ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook").CodeModule.insertLines 22, "    .Range(4) = username"

'Continue Adding Lines back
ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook").CodeModule.insertLines 24, "End With"
ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook").CodeModule.insertLines 25, "'ElseIf"
ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook").CodeModule.insertLines 26, "Unload SavePrompt"
ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook").CodeModule.insertLines 28, "End Sub"

'''CLOSE WORKBOOK W/O BEFORE SAVE
Application.EnableEvents = False
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close
Application.EnableEvents = True

SourceRow = SourceRow + 1 
Loop

End Sub
```