# Macro to Insert VBA code automatically from Personal.xlsb to one predefined sheet of my activeworkbook

Tags: excel, vba

I just wonder if there is way to run a macro from Personal.xlsb in order to insert code in the Sheet3(stack) of my active workbook and run the code.

The code that I would like to insert in the Sheet3(stack) of my active workbook is the following one:

```
Const FontSize As Integer = 12
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
LargeSize = FontSize * 1.2
With Cells.Rows
       .Font.Size = FontSize
       .Interior.Color = xlNone
End With
With Target.EntireRow
        .Font.Size = LargeSize
        .Interior.Color = 49407
End With
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48812402/9199828) there is an example about deleting VBA code with VBA. It can help you to design something to add code instead of deleting.

Comment: It is possible to automatically insert the code, but how to simulate/run an sheet event? Which `Target` parameter to be passed to the function? In order to write code to a module you need a reference to 'Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3'. You can create what you need like an Event, using `...Module.CreateEventProc` and rest of the lines to be inserted inside. You can just run a similar piece of code for the active sheet, active cell...

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply FaneDuru and Foxfire but it does not seems to be obvious for me, I do not have enought skills in VBA to do that , I checked on Internet the .Module.CreateEventProc, the use of this functionnaliy seems to be quite complicated...the 2 website I checked are: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa221350(v%3Doffice.11)

Comment: http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Excel_VBproject_en.html

Comment: Unfortunately I did not manage to find the solution of my problem...